# How to break a for loop in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var delayTime=800;
   for(var i=1;i<20;i++)
     {
       $("#slide"+i).delay(delayTime).fadeIn();
       delayTime=delayTime+800;

     }
```

when I click on a button value of "i" should be "0". I tried so much but I didn't reach solution. help me

Comment: sorry... not sure what you mean... there is nothing related to click here

Comment: The loop starts and finishes executing *before* the animations start - as the animations are run asynchronously. One way to handle this task would be to - based on a flag - add a new animation (if 'continuing') in the *completion callback* of the active animation. It would also be possible to *cancel* all [other] pending animations to "break" the animation loop. And if something else is meant .. I have no idea what it is.

Comment: The question is missing some code ..Please add the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure you want something like this?

```
$('#reset').on('click', function(){
  start();
});

function start(){
  var delayTime = 800;
  $('[id*="slide"]').finish().hide();
  for(var i=1; i<20; i++) {
    $("#slide"+i).delay(delayTime).fadeIn();
    delayTime+=delayTime;
  }
}
```

If i get you wrong, please give me more information about your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much brother, I tried so many ways, so many days. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

the answer to the question "How to break a for loop in jQuery?" is `return false`, but it has nothing to do with the code you have shown